# How can I stop the right floated nav content from overflowing when the window is resized

Tags: html, css

Trying to set up a simple 'cheat sheet' of logo and nav bar that I can reuse. I'm having trouble preventing the right floated nav from overflowing into content below.

NB. I'm new to this so I have added borders to all elements to help me see what's happening.

I have tried to add a clear:left (even though I know it should be clear:right as the content has been floated right) to the element proceeding the navigation but that did not work of course!

```
*{
box-sizing: border-box;
}
header{
  display: inline-block;
}
.logo{
    background-image: url("logo.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width: 140px;
    height: 81px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

nav{
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: right;
    width: auto;
}
  ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
    vertical-align: middle;

  }
li{
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid yellow;

}
.divider{
  clear: both;
}

    <header>
      <div class="logo"></div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Portfolio</li>
        <li>Shopping</li>
        <li>Contact Me</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <main>
    <h1>The display Property</h1>
```

So next I tried clear:both and that did not work.

I have also tried to set the nav to display:inline-block but that did not work.

Ideally I would like to solve this without using any pre-provided templates and my just raw code or display:flex.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please Post your code or better if you create jsfiddle

Comment: Hi HaSnen I have added the code…

Answer (score -2):

Hope this helps.

```css
.nav_bar {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;

    background-color: #00021a;
    color: white;
}

.logo {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 7%;
}

.logo img {
    height: auto;
    width: 50px;
}

.nav {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 90%;
}

.nav_container li {
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<div class="nav_bar">
    <div class="nav_container">

        <div class="logo">
            <img class="logo"
                 src="https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/71/26/83/240_F_71268376_KIbJvY0SYwlvikWpahjNCv5IBfukykG9.jpg"/>
        </div>

        <nav class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li>About</li>
                <li>Portfolio</li>
                <li>Shopping</li>
                <li>Contact Me</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/unitedideas/qhpmure3/2/)

Comment: Hi Shane thanks for your responses - I'm thinking I might not want to use Flexbox on this occasion… so is there any other way with simple code for a beginner?